# Cannot embed Git LFS .mp4 files in HTML page video tag?

Tags: git, video, github, git-lfs

In my github repository, I cannot access files stored in git lfs when writing up an HTML page, and I think it's because of the `src=` aspect of the tag.

So I recently installed `git-lfs` and it seems that the files are stored (when I do `git lfs ls-files` the file shows up. I am currently storing `.mp4` files in my lfs, but when it comes to using the `<video>` tag in the HTML of my `repositoryname.github.io` page, it shows as "no video with the supported format and MIME type found" in the video element.

I've tried `src="../file.mp4"` and `src="file.mp4"` and `src="https://repositoryname.github.io/file.mp4"` and `src="https://github.com/repositoryname/repositoryname.github.io.git/info/lfs/file.mp4"` (where `git lfs env` says the endpoint is) but nothing has worked so far.

I don't want upload it to a video streaming site and then embed it in the page, and `src="../file.mp4"` and `src="file.mp4"` work for smaller video files that are not in `git lfs` storage.

Any possible solutions? I'm not sure if I missed something as to how to link/embed files, but I'm very, very, new to git and git-lfs, so please go easy on me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Getting the file

I'm not 100% sure it works for videos, but I noticed that on the current version of the web UI, you have a "Download" button instead of the "Raw" and "Blame" buttons for files tracked with LFS.

Clicking on the "Download" button takes you to a place different from what the output of `git lfs env` indicates.

In the case of an image, I see the following URL:

```
https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/{USER}/{REPO}/master/{PATH_TO_FILE}
```

Some images: (sorry not enough reputation to embed them)

- [Check this link to see how the toolbar looks for files stored with Git LFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX0Gf.png)
- [Check this link to see how the toolbar looks for files stored with plain Git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVgTi.png)

## About `entrypoint` URL you get with `git lfs env`

If I get it right, the Git LFS protocol says that *blobs* and *not files* should be fetched from here, using the sha256 and size of real files.

Further more, the [server API specifications](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tree/master/docs/api) seem to indicate that this entrypoint is a public API which reads JSON requests (containing information about the file to fetch) rather than using the document path from the HTTP request…

Comment: This was a bit confusing at first but that's because I can be a bit thick-headed sometimes. After countless hours of searching this is exactly what I needed! I would plus 1 if I could, so thanks (and yes i know these comments are to be avoided but this is great!)